# I am trying to install bcrypt. This s error it gives me

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\code-point-at\1.1.0\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token 's' at 1:1
npm ERR! sEDU
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\code-point-at\1.1.0\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\greenstand\2\0105\treetracker-mobile-api-master\treetracker-mobile-api-master\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Check your `package.json` --->`Failed to parse package.json data.`

Comment: npm cache clean

Solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

like muthukumar said in the comment

```
npm cache clean
```

if it doesn't work  try : 
 
1- Delete 'node_modules' folder 
2- npm cache clean 
3- npm update